# 2 column layout with python code inside- overlapping problem

Tags: listings, multicol, pythontex

I am using following latex code to write my appendix to which I need to add python code.

```
\section{Appendix}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsection{Source Code}
\definecolor{keywords}{RGB}{255,0,90}
\definecolor{comments}{RGB}{0,0,113}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,150,0}

 \lstset{language=Python, 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    commentstyle=\color{comments},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    identifierstyle=\color{green},
    procnamekeys={def,class}}
    %taking python file and adding code here
    \lstinputlisting{code/Logic_K.py}
\end{multicols}
\end{landscape}
```

This code produces exactly what I need, so I have landscape page with 2 columns and code is formatted properly. The problem is that some of the long lines in python file overlap to the second column in the latex file. Could someone help me out here so that the listing function does not overlap to the next column but rather goes to the next line in the same column? I would greatly appropriate any help since it is very important.
Also, would it be possible to make the listed code with a smaller font size so that more code can fit each column on a single page?

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Please make sure to  also include the relevant part of your preamble (from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}` as this can change things a lot.  Also, you may want to have a look at the [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package which offers line wrapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to tell `listings` what you want, hence change your `lsset` to

```
 \lstset{language=Python, 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    commentstyle=\color{comments},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    identifierstyle=\color{green},
    procnamekeys={def,class},
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{your symbol for line break}}
```

`breaklines` will allow `listings` to do the linebreak, and the other parameter will print a symbol on the new line if a linebreak occurs (use your own symbol, although `\hookrightarrow` are comonly used).

**EDIT**

To solve the fontsize issue, replace the line for `commentstyle` with the following one :

```
commentstyle=\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont\color{comments}
```

Comment: works just the way I wanted it, what about size of the text? Any quick fixes to make the text smaller?

Comment: Does something like `commentstyle=\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont\color{comments}` or `commentstyle=\scriptsize\color{comments}`work?

Comment: All right, I will update the answer so that it fits all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly to answer your last point.  I used Latin Modern anyway for my thesis, so by putting

```
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\fontseries{lc}\selectfont,
```

in my `\lstset` I could use "Latin Modern Typewriter Light Condensed" ([here](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/robertson/robertson.pdf)'s a nice writeup of Latin Modern).  This was the narrowest monospaced font I could find (freely available), and actually looks quite nice.  My line numbering used `\tiny`. I didn't use a line continuation symbol, just `breakindent=0.5em`

I didn't have a two-column layout (and would avoid it for code-appendices, but that's up to you if you're lucky).  I also had some rather long lines.